# Xamarin Forms/Andriod file picker plugin exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using [Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker/) Plugin Latest version 2.1.18 
I follow all instruction and check for ***WriteExternalStorage*** and ***ReadExternalStorage*** Permissions before call `PickFile` method

```
var fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
```

It works at first and open the file picker dialog after i choose any file 
the following error occur

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.MissingMethodException: string[]
>   string.Split(char,System.StringSplitOptions) occurred

Comment: Make sure that you've updated the package on all your platform projects and they have the same version

Comment: All are up to date still error occur unfortunately

Comment: What's going on? I see the same problem. Everything worked and now plugin does not pick file of any type on Android

{System.MissingMethodException: string[] string.Split(char,System.StringSplitOptions)
  at Plugin.FilePicker.FilePickerActivity.OnActivityResult (System.Int32 requestCode, Android.App.Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data) [0x00039] in D:\a\1\s\src\Plugin.FilePicker\Android\FilePickerActivity.android.cs:151